# Why in viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) the code execute sequential?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that in Kotlin , by default "**suspend**" is a sequential functions.
OK.
But here snippet in my ViewModel:

import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope

```
 private fun finishProcessRecognizedCheck(
        firebaseVisionImage: FirebaseVisionImage,
        firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText, recognizedCheck: Check
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_1")
            val file_prefix = resultRecognizedCheckList.size.toString()
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_2")
            RecognizedCheckDataService.saveRecognizedImage(firebaseVisionImage, file_prefix)
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_3")
            RecognizedCheckDataService.saveRecognizedText(firebaseVisionText, file_prefix)
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_4")
            resultRecognizedCheckList.add(recognizedCheck)
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_5")
            val firstFindIndex = resultRecognizedCheckList.indexOf(recognizedCheck)
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_6")
            val filterList = resultRecognizedCheckList.filter { it.equals(recognizedCheck) }
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_7")
            howOftenCheckIndexMap.put(firstFindIndex, filterList.size)
            Debug.d(TAG ,"step_8")
            //Debug.d(TAG, "finishProcessRecognizedCheck: howOftenCheckMap = $howOftenCheckMap")
        }
}

        fun saveRecognizedImage(
            firebaseVisionImage: FirebaseVisionImage,
            fileNameSuffix: String? = null
        ): File? {
            try {
                val bitmap = firebaseVisionImage.bitmap
                val resultFileName = getImageFileName(fileNameSuffix)
                val file =
                    AndroidFileUtil.saveBitmapToFolder(
                        bitmap, recognizedCheckDataDir!!.absolutePath,
                        resultFileName, IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSTION_FORMAT
                    )
                Debug.d(TAG, "saveRecognizedImage: finish")
                return file
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Debug.e(TAG, "saveRecognizedImage: error = $ex", ex)
                return null
            }
}

   fun saveRecognizedText(
            firebaseVisionText: FirebaseVisionText,
            fileNameSuffix: String? = null
        ): File? {
            try {
                val recognizedText = firebaseVisionText.text
                val resultFileName = getTextFileName(fileNameSuffix)
                val file =
                    AndroidFileUtil.saveTextToFile(
                        recognizedText,
                        recognizedCheckDataDir!!.absolutePath,
                        resultFileName
                    )
                Debug.d(TAG, "saveRecognizedText: finish")
                return file
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Debug.e(TAG, "saveRecognizedText: error = $ex", ex)
                return null
            }
        }
```

Here log

```
02-05 20:37:53.748 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_1
02-05 20:37:53.748 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_2

02-05 20:37:54.693 D/CheckDataService( 6531): saveRecognizedImage: finish
02-05 20:37:54.693 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_3
02-05 20:37:54.698 D/CheckDataService( 6531): saveRecognizedText: finish
02-05 20:37:54.698 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_4
02-05 20:37:54.698 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_5
02-05 20:37:54.698 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_6
02-05 20:37:54.698 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_7
02-05 20:37:54.699 D/ViewModel( 6531): step_8
```

as you can see the functions `saveRecognizedImage` and `saveRecognizedText` **ARE NOT SUSPEND** functions. But in

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

...
}
```

all code is executed **sequentially**.

Why?

Comment: All your logs are in the same function, so they will print out in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the blog post [Kotlin Coroutines in Android](https://sourcediving.com/kotlin-coroutines-in-android-e2d5bb02c275):

> Suspending functions can invoke any other regular functions, but to actually suspend the execution, it has to be another suspending function.

Since your two "regular" functions are called from within the "suspendable" block of code, they will be executed as part of this block.